# Save Checked item is listview

Tags: c#, android, list, xamarin.android

I have a listview with a checkbox on each row and I need to make it so that if the user exits the app and later comes back to that liistview the same items remain checked, I have succesfully saved the checked items, but If I try to recheck them in the `getview()` method the list starts to lag, and random checkboxes start getting checked.

Below is my code that rechecks the boxes

```
 using (VehicleFeaturesDB vfdb = new VehicleFeaturesDB())
      {
          selectedfeatures = vfdb.GetSelectedFeatures(Selector.vehicleId);

          if (listOfSelectedFeatures != null)
          {
              foreach (Features f in listOfSelectedFeatures)
              {
                  if (feature.FeatureID == f.FeatureID)
                  {
                      CheckBox.Checked = true;
                  }
              }
          }

      }
```

Tha

Answer (score 1):

If that using block is in GetView(), you're connecting to the database and pulling the list of features every time a new item is displayed.  That's why you're seeing the lag.

You're also not setting Checked to false if the feature is not in the list, so when you reuse the convertview the checkbox may already be checked.  That's why you're seeing the random boxes checked.

I would probably get the selected features in your adapter's constructor, then reference that list in your GetView().  Something like this should work for you.

```
public class MyAdapter...
{
    private IEnumerable<SelectedFeature> selectedFeatures;
    public MyAdapter()
    {
        ...your code...
        using (VehicleFeaturesDB vfdb = new VehicleFeaturesDB())
        {
            selectedfeatures = vfdb.GetSelectedFeatures(Selector.vehicleId);
        }
    }

    public override View GetView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ...your code...
        CheckBox.Checked = selectedFeatures.Any(sf => sf.FeatureID == feature.FeatureID);
    }
```